# Angular - Button focus is lost when changing back and forth between windows

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a toolbar of buttons that are gray by default but when one button is clicked on that button is made white to indicate that that is the page you are on. This is achieved using a class and the below css.

```
.btn-details:focus {
      color: #fff;
 }
```

This works fine except when I change windows and then go back. For example, if I have my page open it is working find, then I switch to an Excel window and then back to my page the white highlighting is now gone. How can I keep the button in focus even when the window is changed?

Comment: Are you using keyboard controls for which you need the focus on that button even when switching windows? 

In case you are only looking for a way to keep the clicked the button highlighted, then appending a CSS class for changing background or border should be sufficient and just remove the CSS class if you click on anything other clickable item on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue with that solution is that I don't have separate html for each button, I have a list of buttons and an *ngFor loop that displays each of them. If I give one an ID to use to append a class then it will append that class to all the buttons.

Comment: Created an example for you using angular. https://angular-p38ql3.stackblitz.io
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think you need to take your time to focus on how CSS works.

You are using the: focus selector. Know that it does what you asked it to. If the button loses focus and your style no longer holds.
I think this is exactly what happens when you use other apps.

I advise you to add a CSS class on the button clicked and to remove this same class on the other buttons.

If you have difficulty implementing this, please come back to me. I would make a small example depending on your level.

See you soon !

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I definitely don't have a thorough understanding of CSS and a simple example would be incredibly helpful.